# How to apply a function on a list column and return another one in dplyr and purrr?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want to take the first 5 values in each vector which is in a list-column and return it as a new column in the data frame saved as a list.

```
structure(list(sample_num = 1:6, vector = list(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 10, 12, 1), c(1, 33, 
4, 4, 2, 2, 6, 9, 14, 2), c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5, 3, 0), c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("sample_num", 
"vector"))

> test
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  sample_num     vector
       <int>     <list>
1          1 <dbl [10]>
2          2 <dbl [10]>
3          3 <dbl [10]>
4          4 <dbl [10]>
5          5 <dbl [10]>
6          6 <dbl [10]>
```

I try to use lmap but I got error message

```
> test  %>% lmap(.$vector,.f = function(x) x[1:5])
Error in .f(.x[i], ...) : 
  unused argument (list(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 10, 12, 1), c(1, 33, 4, 4, 2, 2, 6, 9, 14, 2), c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5, 3, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
structure(list(sample_num = 1:6, vector = list(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 10, 12, 1), c(1, 33, 
4, 4, 2, 2, 6, 9, 14, 2), c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5, 3, 0), c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("sample_num", 
"vector"))

test$new = lapply(test$vector, function(x) {x[1:5]})
test

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  sample_num     vector       new
       <int>     <list>    <list>
1          1 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
2          2 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
3          3 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
4          4 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
5          5 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
6          6 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>


test$vector[3]
[[1]]
 [1]  1 33  4  4  2  2  6  9 14  2

test$new[3]
[[1]]
[1]  1 33  4  4  2
```

If you want to use the dplyr syntax, define a function first:

```
f = function(x) {
    return(list(x[1:5]))
    }
```

Then, apply it row-wise to the column `vector`

```
test = test %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(new_dplyr = f(vector))

test
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  sample_num     vector new_dplyr
       <int>     <list>    <list>
1          1 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
2          2 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
3          3 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
4          4 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
5          5 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
6          6 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>

test$vector[3]
[[1]]
 [1]  1 33  4  4  2  2  6  9 14  2

test$new_dplyr[3]
[[1]]
[1]  1 33  4  4  2
```

Comment: Yes! I guess I missed the { } when defining the anonymous function. Is there other way that we can use pipe operation?

Answer (score 3):

This uses a compact sequence of calls. I first tried using '[' as I would have used with an lapply or sapply usage, but needed backticks to make it succeed:

```
> test$new <- map(test$vector,.f = `[`,  1:5)
> test
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  sample_num     vector       new
       <int>     <list>    <list>
1          1 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
2          2 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
3          3 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
4          4 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
5          5 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
6          6 <dbl [10]> <dbl [5]>
```